# Alternative to If in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, textbox, overriding

Question asked in interview :

Scenario : Username,password textboxes ,if kept empty a label pops up saying respective element or both elements are empty.
Using single method cover all 3 scenarios and print respective label output without using any condition.

I tried saying using ternary operator but he said no condition is allowed even ternary operator.
So I told method overriding and passing 3 parameters based on 3 conditions. I dont think he was satisfied by answer. Please tell what is correct answer

Comment: You can use something like `List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.tagName"label")); for (WebElement label: labes) {   System.out.println(label.getText());   }` It will work no matter how many labes are found including zero. Still what's the point avoiding `if` conditions?

Comment: Yes I too didn't get the point in avoiding if. The code should be clean and efficient. It was asked in interview by interviewer.

Comment: It's about code complexity and readability. If your code is understandable even with bunch of `if`s there is no point to get rid of them.